# ошибка в speech_recognition, что делать?

Tags: python, распознавание-речи

Хотел написать своего голосового ассистента на python. Отталкиваясь от этого видео https://youtu.be/YeS755SPSI8. Делал всё по порядку. дошёл до проверки модуля speech_recognition.
Код взял самый простой проверочный со страницы модуля. Микрофон определил. Вот код:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone(device_index=1) as source:
    print("скажите что нибудь...")
    audio = r.listen(source)

query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
print ("вы сказали: " + query.lower())
```

Но выдаёт ошибку:

```
D:\Python3.8\python.exe D:/eva/eva.py
скажите что нибудь...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/eva/eva.py", line 7, in <module>
    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language="ru-RU")
  File "D:\Python3.8\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Помогите пожалуйста. Я в программирование недавно.

Comment: Проблема с той же ошибкой в репозитории библиотеки: https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/383

Comment: flac надо установить. А вообще лучше попробовать https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

я нашёл ответ!!! у меня не работа микрофон. и заменив на другой всё заработало!